# How we write Recurrence functions and Generate individual components using given condition

Tags: differential-equations, difference-equations

How we write the recurrence function of below code so that it can easily find remaining components such as U[3], U[4], etc.

```
U[0] = 0;
U[1] = 1;
U[2] = 0;
U[k_] := U[k] =1/k^2 ((k - 1) U[k - 1] + U[k - 1] + 1/Factorial[k - 1] - (-1)^(
      k - 2)/Factorial[k - 2] + (k - 1) (k - 2) U[k - 1] - 1/(
      2 Factorial[k - 3]) + (-1)^(k - 3)/(2  Factorial[k - 3]));
```

Comment: Try `RSolve`!  Probably your initial conditions are overdetermined because your recurrence-equation is 1st order.

Comment: Rsolve solve it for n values but I want to solve it using component by componet, so plz suggest me how we write a function for that particular situations.

Answer (score 1):

Try `RSolveValue`

```
u = RSolveValue[{U[k] == (1/(k^2))(-(1/(2 (-3 + k)!)) + (-1)^(-3 + k)/(2 (-3 + k)!) + (-1)^(-1 + k)/(-2 + k)! +1/(-1 + k)! +U[-1 + k] + (-1 + k) U[-1 + k] + (-2 + k)(-1 + k) U[-1 + k]), 
U[0] == 0  }, U, k] // Simplify
```

which evaluates the analytical solution of your reccurence equation with starting value `U[0==0]`

```
Table[u[k], {k, 0, 5}] // N // Chop
(*{0, 1., 0.5, 0.444444, 0.194444, 0.140556}*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: @ AnilKumar You're welcome

Comment: would you solve my latest query, which posted sometime before.